# what happens to the messages in rabbitmq when the servers crashes

Tags: rabbitmq

I have a very minimal knowledge on rabbitmq. My question is when the producer publishes the message in the queue what happens to the messages in the queue when the server crashes. Will it be stored if yes, where would it be stored. I have used the quorum queue for its replication property wasnt able to locate where the replicas are stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the file system location, please read:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/relocate.html#unix

The location is (usually) `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia` where inside the hostname directory, you can find the `quorum` directory. The queue name is something like:

```
2F_TOP7LVMTT5H2WBR/
```

That is the virtual host + the hash of the queue name.

The quorum queue (https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html) replicates the messages across the cluster.

If one node crashes, you have the copy to the other nodes.